# installing Kong API Gateway on EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, kong

Following the super-simple instructions in [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/deployment/eks/) link (the helm method) I'm trying to install Kong on an test EKS cluster (in an empty kong namespace) and it's a disaster. The service never gets an external IP (stuck at "pending"). The ingress-controller container inside the main pod fails with:

```
time="2022-06-15T19:14:52Z" level=info msg="successfully synced configuration to kong."
time="2022-06-15T19:14:54Z" level=error msg="checking config status failed: %!w(*kong.APIError=&{500 An unexpected error occurred})"
time="2022-06-15T19:14:57Z" level=error msg="checking config status failed: %!w(*kong.APIError=&{500 An unexpected error occurred})"
time="2022-06-15T19:15:00Z" level=error msg="checking config status failed: %!w(*kong.APIError=&{500 An unexpected error occurred})"
```

(the last line repeating every 3sec)

...while the proxy container inside the same pod fails with repeating

```
2022/06/15 19:47:27 [error] 1110#0: *11302 [lua] api_helpers.lua:511: handle_error(): /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:424: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/routes/health.lua:45: http2 requests not supported yet
```

I'm not doing any customizing with the values file, I'm just installing as it comes by default. The instructions (just a "helm repo add" and a "helm install") come from the official Kong site, so what is amiss?? Helm is v3.8, K8s is v1.21.

Comment: I think your two issues are unrelated. The reason it's never getting an external IP is probably because of some issue with your LB controller setup / subnet tagging / etc... The other issue (the logs) are benign, I think it's just a warning as we added some http2 stuff but it's not fulling working yet, but shouldn't affect the proxy / ingress controller operation itself, see: https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/8690

Comment: I abandoned the Helm method and tried the plain manifest method, from the same doc. Now both containers in the pod are running fine, no errors. However I still can't get an LB. Can you please elaborate on the tagging thing you mentioned?